# What is wrong about this code in Scala? (Long required)

Tags: eclipse, scala, types, long-integer

I'm newbie in using Scala, and most of the time I don't know how to deal with error messages. Can someone help me with this code? What do I need to change to make this code work? Btw, I'm writing Euklid's Greatest Common Divisor in Scala.

```
  def userInput() {
    var x: String = Console.readLine("Please enter the first number you want to calculate. ")
    var y: String = Console.readLine("Please enter the second number you want to calculate. ")
    println(userInput())
  }

  def ggt(firstNumber: Long, secondNumber: Long): Long = {
    var x = firstNumber
    var y = secondNumber

    if (y == 0) {
      return x
    }

  }
```

And the error I get is  "type mismatch; found : Unit required: Long" in this line:
    if (y == 0) {

What should I change? Thanks in advance for your guys help!

Comment: I don't know Scala, but since it's JVM-based, what about `y == 0L`?

Comment: @m0skit0 In Scala there is an implicit conversion from int to long, so in this case Scala compiler resolves int to long

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if you want to read numbers from the command line, then your userInput is incorrect, it should be something like this:

```
def readNumbers(): (Long, Long) = {
  println("Print the first number")
  val first = Console.readLong()
  println("Println the seconds number")
  val second = Console.readLong()
  (first, second)
}
```

Then read numbers:

```
val (a, b) = readNumbers()
```

GCD method:

```
def gcd(a: Long, b: Long): Long = if (b == 0) a else gcd(b, a % b)
```

and call it on the numbers:

```
gcd(a, b)
```

Scala is a functional on the one hand, so every expression results in some value, and in Scala if is an expression, not a statement.

Comment: wow, I'm learning a lot through this site, thank you very much!

Answer (score 13):

Your `ggt` function needs to return a `Long` and it's not always doing so.  First, you can remove the `return` keyword because scala functions will always return whatever is on the last line.  Then, you need a return value when `y != 0` to make this function definition valid.  Right now, it's returning `Unit` which is like `void` because there is no else block there.  Change to something like this and you should be all set:

```
def ggt(firstNumber: Long, secondNumber: Long): Long = {
  var x = firstNumber
  var y = secondNumber

  if (y == 0) x
  else y
}
```

Comment: I didn't even think of continue writing the code with "else" when I saw the error... But thanks a lot! :)

Comment: amko23, this seems to be the right answer, you should accept it ;)